# JSONSchema validation implementation in Rust

Tags: rust, library

I'm developing a [Rust library](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs) that implements JSONSchema validation (Drafts 7 fully works at the moment). I have Rust-specific questions and concerns about my implementation.

It works by compiling the input schema first and validating the data after it:

```
use jsonschema::{JSONSchema, Draft};
use serde_json::json;

let schema = json!({"maxLength": 5});
let instance = json!("foo");
let compiled = JSONSchema::compile(&schema, Some(Draft::Draft7));
let result = compiled.validate(&instance);
```

**Main points**:

- Input schema is parsed into a tree of structs that implement a common trait -
  `Validate` that provides `validate` method ([code](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/keywords/mod.rs#L40));
- Each struct in this tree have different members that may refer to the original schema (e.g. holding a vector of strings for "required" keyword) or have some computed values, e.g. regex ([example](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/keywords/properties.rs#L8));
- During validation, the input value is passed to this tree and it is validated by specific nodes ([code](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/validator.rs#L42));
- `validate` returns `Result<(), ValidationError>`, where the error case contains data needed for displaying errors. This data is copied from schema or instance or constructed dynamically [somewhere](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/keywords/property_names.rs#L28) in the tree;
- When resolving a reference, a `Cow` is [returned](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/resolver.rs#L50). `Borrowed` for cases when the referenced document exists in `instance` and `Owned` when it is loaded from a remote location (e.g. `{"$ref": "http://localhost/schema.json"}`);
- A new validation [tree](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/keywords/ref_.rs#L27) is generated for resolved schemas and validation goes further with this new tree;

**My concerns**:

1. `Validate` trait. Is it a good approach to build a validation tree? What are the alternatives for such a case?
2. Is it possible to avoid copying to `ValidationError` and use references when possible? In some cases, objects are generated / loaded from a remote location, during validation and have different lifetime than schema or instance. In this case, probably the data should be owned - is it possible to have `ValidationError` working for both cases?

**Code**

Trait ([actual code](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/keywords/mod.rs#L40)):

```
pub trait Validate<'a>: Send + Sync + 'a {
    fn validate(&self, schema: &JSONSchema, instance: &Value) -> ValidationResult;
    fn name(&self) -> String;
}

impl<'a> Debug for dyn Validate<'a> + Send + Sync + 'a {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), Error> {
        f.write_str(&self.name())
    }
}

pub type ValidationResult = Result<(), error::ValidationError>;
pub type CompilationResult<'a> = Result<BoxedValidator<'a>, error::CompilationError>;
pub type BoxedValidator<'a> = Box<dyn Validate<'a> + Send + Sync + 'a>;
pub type Validators<'a> = Vec<BoxedValidator<'a>>;
```

`ValidationError` ([actual code](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/error.rs#L24)):

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct ValidationError {
    kind: ValidationErrorKind,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum ValidationErrorKind {
    FalseSchema(Value),
    // ...
}
```

Validation node example ([actual code](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/src/keywords/properties.rs#L8)):

```
pub struct PropertiesValidator<'a> {
    properties: Vec<(&'a String, Validators<'a>)>,
}

impl<'a> PropertiesValidator<'a> {
    pub(crate) fn compile(
        schema: &'a Value,
        context: &CompilationContext,
    ) -> CompilationResult<'a> {
        match schema {
            Value::Object(map) => {
                let mut properties = Vec::with_capacity(map.len());
                for (key, subschema) in map {
                    properties.push((key, compile_validators(subschema, context)?));
                }
                Ok(Box::new(PropertiesValidator { properties }))
            }
            _ => Err(CompilationError::SchemaError),
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> Validate<'a> for PropertiesValidator<'a> {
    fn validate(&self, schema: &JSONSchema, instance: &Value) -> ValidationResult {
        if let Value::Object(item) = instance {
            for (name, validators) in self.properties.iter() {
                if let Some(item) = item.get(*name) {
                    for validator in validators {
                        validator.validate(schema, item)?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    }
    // ...
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=30e02dbd1d2354c127d9f3cbba2b99f3) for a smaller version;

[Dependencies](https://github.com/Stranger6667/jsonschema-rs/blob/master/Cargo.toml)

**Rust version**: 1.42.0